# Configuring a compiler for Qt

Tags: qt, compiler-construction, path

I have been attempting to learn how to use Qt. So far, setup for this program has proven to be a miserable process. I've downloaded the 5.1 Windows 64 bit offline with VS 2012. I tried to run a simple program and received an error telling me to "configure the compiler". After extensive research I thought I configured the compiler. Then I received an error telling me that the "path or permission wrong". After fussing with it for hours, I uninstalled and downloaded it again. Now I'm attempting to configure the compiler before I build a program, but no compilers are being detected. VS was downloaded with Qt so I don't understand why it wouldn't detect a compiler within it's own directory. I have no idea how to set this program up. Setups seem so vastly different that researching it is a nightmare. If anyone can help that would be great.

Comment: VS is not downloaded with Qt.  What you probably downloaded is a package targeted for MSVC 2012.  You need to download MSVC++ from Microsoft and install it.  You may want to start with C++ first before moving on to Qt.   [Getting started with C++ for windoze](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa733747%28v=vs.60%29.aspx).  [Adding compilers to Qt Creator](http://qt-project.org/doc/qtcreator-2.8/creator-tool-chains.html).  and lastly, there's a bunch of [examples you should take a close look at](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtdoc/qtexamplesandtutorials.html).

Comment: Thank you. I just ended up downloading the MinGW (older) version. I have been learning C++ for awhile and felt that Qt would be a nice way to continue learning to program. Beginning to lose interest in the console, though it is fun.